# SQL Developer: Compare / fuzzy name matching 2 columns in the same table

Tags: sql, comparison

I have a table with amongst others the following columns: Reference, Debit Party Name and Credit Party Name. These fields contains names. I need to find those records in which the Originator name is 'more or less' the same as the Beneficiary name.

For example: Mr. Joe Smith  vs J. Smith should give me a 'potential' match. It would be nice if certain predefined keywords can be taken out of the comparison e.g. 'Mr.' 'Mrs.' 'Mister', 'Miss' etc. Also, any special character like '.' and ',' should be ignored.

I have seen many posts e.g. Levenshtein distance but my table contains millions of records and I need to search per each individual row only.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Are you using Oracle? (SQL Developer indicates Oracle.)